# Optimize java application for a remote database

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am optimizing my java application for a remote Oracle database. I have set up connection pooling with C3P0 and I'm now looking to find places where I can reduce the number of calls to the remote database. Is there a function in SQL Developer, or some other tool, that will show me how many times the database is getting hit with queries? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of tools that DBAs use to know what queries are taking a long time.  These tools will really only show you what connection made those calls.  If you want to pinpoint what parts of code are being hit the most / slowest, you'd need a code profilier, such as VisualVM, JRockit Mission Control.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of anything at the server end that will do this, but could you build a mechanism in to your data access class ( if they all extend the same base class for example ) that could produce these stats for you?